# Limiting distribution of separated points in a unit square

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-probability

Let $n$ and $r$ be fixed, and consider the following process, with $S=\emptyset$ to start:

- For $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$:

  - Sample a random point $X$ in the unit square.
  - If $X$ is a distance at least $r$ from all points in $S$, add it to $S$.

My question is, what is the distribution of the size of $S$ after the process completes?  I am interested in limiting behavior, e.g. setting $r=c/\sqrt{n}$ for fixed $c$ and letting $n\to\infty$.